# get values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a script that creates an array in the following format

```
  $named_array["vehicles"][0]['vehicle'] = "i100-1 "  ;
  $named_array["vehicles"][1]['vehicle'] = "i100-2 "  ;
  $named_array["vehicles"][2]['vehicle'] = "i100-46 "  ;
```

What I want to do later in the script is get the index value[0-1-2 etc] from $named_array
but I only have the value ( i100-1 etc)  as a query option , This is so I can alter it later. What I want to achieve is something like , what is the index value of `$named_array` where value is i100-2

this is output to json at the end .

I hope this makes sense ! any help please ?

Comment: I really don't understand what your desired result is. I also don't see why you need to add another dimension for `vehicle` in an array of `vehicles`.

Comment: Prince I want a vehicle array in vehicles that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function complex_index_of($named_array, $val){
    for($i=0, $n=count($named_array['vehicles']); $i<$n; $i++){
        if ($named_array['vehicles'][$i]['vehicle'] == $val)
            return $i;
    }
    return -1;
}


echo complex_index_of($named_array, 'i100-2 ');
// output: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (maybe create a function, if you need to do it more than once)

```
$needle = 'i100-1';
$vIndex = -1;
foreach ($named_array["vehicles"] as $index => $data) {
    if($data['vehicle'] == $needle) {
        $vIndex = $index;
        break;
    }
}
```